# Found big issue in cross-compiling, jamvm

Tags: cross-compiling, embedded-linux, glibc, gnu-toolchain, jamvm

I have been trying for a while to cross-compile jamvm (including GNU classpath) for an embedded linux (2.6) and I am stuck in a delicate place.

I will try to sum up: after a lot of errors I finally compiled the package for my architecture but although I specified the --enable-static in the ./configure, when I try to run the jamvm it complains about not finding GLIBC 2.4. The thing is that I have the 2.3.5 version and compiling the 2.4 for my architecture is not an option for the moment (it would mean getting started with a whole new problem).

I suspect the problem comes from building from a machine with a different toolchain than supported by the embedded target.

The thing is that I know the exact gcc, glibc, binutils, and linux kernel headers that match my CPU, but the problem is that I don't know how to incorporate this information in the cross-compiling/build process.

However, perhaps I am wrong assuming that the fact that my machine uses a different toolchain will affect the cross-compiling.

To put it simple, I need to cross-compile jamvm in a way that it does not complain about glibc 2.4 or any other libraries that are not suported by the embedded system (assuming that I know the right toolchain for my architecture)

I would really appreciate any help regarding this issue. I would also appreciate some light on the topic if my reasoning is not correct.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure I understand your problem in 100%, but maybe try to build a list of symbols that are creating the dependency on GLIBC 2.4 by using:

```
$ readelf -Ws <your_jamvm_executable_file> | grep \@GLIBC_2\.4
```

(use a more relaxed `grep` search pattern if you won't find any symbols)

Then, check if the offending symbols have other versions in your GLIBC, that is equal or lower than GLIBC v2.3.5. I'll use `posix_spawn` as an example:

```
(1:517)$ readelf -Ws /lib/libc.so.6 | grep posix_spawn\@
  1666: 000d8800    51 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 posix_spawn@@GLIBC_2.15
  1667: 00127760    51 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   12 posix_spawn@GLIBC_2.2
```

This means that if `posix_spawn` is found to be pulling in GLIBC v2.15, your program can be recompiled to use `posix_spawn` from GLIBC v2.2, deleting the GLIBC 2.15 dependency (if `posix_spawn` is the only symbol pulling in GLIBC v2.15).

You can select which `posix_spawn` version to use by using this directive inside the source code, at the beginning of the unit (`.c` or `.cpp` file) that actually uses the symbol:

```
__asm__(".symver posix_spawn,posix_spawn@GLIBC_2.2");
```

Sorry if this is not what you're asking about.

Comment: Thank you, the problem is that the symbols I have don't have other versions of GLIBC. When I run your command I get dependencies only with GLIB_2.4.